# How to save Eclipse call hierarchy search?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse and want to extract call hierarchies of two methods to see if their flows intersect. What I'm currently doing is copying one method call hierarchy to a text editor and searching the other method call hierarchy for methods in the first call hierarchy.

1. Is there a way to save a call hierarchy, other then copy paste, so that it can be reloaded into the search window later?
2. Is there another way to check call hierarchy intersections of existing Java code? (Other tools maybe?)

Comment: How do you copy the call hierarchy to a text editor? I am looking for this in Eclipse CDT (ARM DS), but there is no apparent way to copy the tree to the clipboard and paste it in a text editor.

Comment: Nevermind - found that. If one function at most is selected, then in the context menu (right-click) you get a "Copy expanded hierarchy" entry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate your problem into 2 different tasks

1. Get stack trace and save it
2. Find intersections.

If you can change the code you are discovering you can just use code like `new Throwable().printStackTrace(out)` to get stack trace in the beginning of each interesting method. Save it to dedicated file and process later.

If you cannot (or do not want) change the code that is being discovered you can easily implement the same with AspectJ. Recommendation: use dynamic weaving, it is easier and more flexible.

Now the second task: searching for intersections. Unfortunately I do not know standard tools, but it seems that it is not so difficult to implement this. The implementation will depend on your requirements. If for example you just have to find the first common method in 2 stack traces the task is trivial. If however you need a real "diff" functionality you can use one of available java diff libraries. If personally found http://badiff.org/wiki/Badiff as a most flexible and well designed java diff library.